# FileObserver to monitor Contacts table in Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to use a file observer on ContactsContract.Contacts table to monitor contact access by an android application?

Thanks,
SK

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use a file observer on ContactsContract.Contacts table to monitor contact access by an android application?

No, because you do not have read access to the relevant files, except perhaps on a rooted device or via a custom ROM.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I have another query. can an application read androidmanifest.xml file of other applications installed on the same device to identify applications applications that have more access permissions than required?